# tikz-cd editor woes

Tags: tikz-cd

I am using an online Tikz-cd editor I found on this site ([link](https://www.tikzcd.yichuanshen.de)). It provides tex code for the diagrams you make, but I am not able to get the code it provides to compile. More Specifically, the code I'm trying to run is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage[numbers, square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{csquotes}[autostyle, english = american]
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
{} \arrow[r, dotted] & {X_{\gamma}} \arrow[r, "F_{\gamma\beta}"] \arrow[d, "h_{\gamma}", hook] & {X_{\beta}} \arrow[r, "f_{\beta\alpha}"] \arrow[d, "h_{\beta}", hook] & {X_{\alpha}} \arrow[d,"h_{\alpha}", hook]\\
{} \arrow[r, dotted] & {X_{\gamma,n}} \arrow[r, "g_{\gamma\beta}:, two heads] & {X_{\beta,n}}\arrow[r, "g_{\beta\alpha}", two heads] & {X_{\alpha,n}}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The error I get says:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \begingroup 
l.730 \end{tikzcd}
```

Any thoughts on how to get this code to compile? I've found some people here have had the same error, the proposed fixes for them haven't worked for me, so I figure there's something up with my preamble?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Two things to do: remove `\MakeOuterQuote{"}` and replace `"g_{\gamma\beta}:` by `"g_{\gamma\beta}"`.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I guess I'll be doing outer quotes the old fashioned way. Thank you. Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are going wrong here:

1. In the second row, one of the arrows is specified as `\arrow[r, "g_{\gamma\beta}:, two heads]`. You should replace `"g_{\gamma\beta}:` with `"g_{\gamma\beta}"` or at least add the missing closing quotation mark.
2. If you really need to use the `csquotes` package, you should not set `\MakeOuterQuote{"}`, because this will make all `"` active and therefore raise an error if you use this character inside, for example, a `tikzcd` environment.

In fact, to create this diagram, you would need no packages other than `tikz-cd`. So, the code should rather look like follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
{} \arrow[r, dotted] & {X_{\gamma}} \arrow[r, "F_{\gamma\beta}"] \arrow[d, "h_{\gamma}", hook] & {X_{\beta}} \arrow[r, "f_{\beta\alpha}"] \arrow[d, "h_{\beta}", hook] & {X_{\alpha}} \arrow[d,"h_{\alpha}", hook]\\
{} \arrow[r, dotted] & {X_{\gamma,n}} \arrow[r, "g_{\gamma\beta}", two heads] & {X_{\beta,n}}\arrow[r, "g_{\beta\alpha}", two heads] & {X_{\alpha,n}}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]